# Static site with netlify + Django on the same url

Tags: django, server, static, jekyll, netlify

Let's assume I own the domain:

```
foobar.com/
```

I want to use Netlify for my static pages like

```
foobar.com/features/
foobar.com/pricing/
foobar.com/imprint/
etc.
```

But I also have a Django application on a seperate server on AWS that has nothing to do with the static sites served by Netlify.

My Django has urls like

```
foobar.com/login/
foobar.com/dashboard/
etc.
```

Is it possible to use Netlify for a few static pages and my Django application for other pages?
I don't know how start or if this is event possible.

Comment: @talves ' answer is the best one, according to Netlify tech support (I work on that team)

Comment: @fool Thanks, just updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on how your Django apps handle the target, but you could use rewrites on Netlify using the HTTP status code 200 with a redirect rule (rewrite).

> If the API supports standard HTTP caching mechanisms like Etags or Last-Modified headers, the responses will even get cached by CDN nodes.

Have DNS set `foobar.com` to the Netlify site.

Decide the domain for the Django site on AWS. (proxy.foobar.com)

Setup `_redirects` at the root of the Netlify site to use [Proxy (rewrites)](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#rewrites-and-proxying) on Netlify

```
/login/*       https://proxy.foobar.com/login/:splat  200
/dashboard/*   https://proxy.foobar.com/dashboard/:splat  200
```

***Note:*** This is how you can incrementally switch a site over to Netlify without having to refactor a site all at once.

Comment: this is the answer that Netlify tech support would have given you if you'd asked us.  It both leverages our CDN and allows you to use dynamic content seamlessly at the same domain

Answer (score 2):

When you set a DNS record (e.g. an A record), you can point `foobar.com` to your AWS server or netlify, but not both.

Perhaps you can put the sites on different domains, for example `dashboard.foobar.com` for your Django site.

You could then [configure netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/) to redirect `foobar.com/dashboard/` to `dashboard.foobar.com/dashboard/`

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't have a `foobar.com` point to two different servers. You'll have to use subdomains, e.g.:

- static.foobar.com -> DNS entry for Netlify
- app.foobar.com -> DNS entry for your Django server

or, what you often see, is:

- foobar.com and www.foobar.com -> DNS pointing to your main website (Netlify)
- api.foobar.com and app.foobar.com -> DNS pointing to your Django app